# JSON Unexpected End

Tags: c#, json

I'm running into an exception that I can't seem to find a lot of information about online.

*Unexpected End. Line #, Position ######*

Some details, this is running on Windows 6.5.3 , the Mobile .NET CE Framework. I'm parsing the response from a web-service call. I have verified that the response is proper JSON formatting, But I know that the response is very, very big.

What I can't figure out, is why I get this excpetion. Here's my parsing code (Yes, we always get lists of complex objects)

```
List<T> objList = new List<T>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    using (JsonTextReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {             
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();          
        JObject jo = ser.Deserialize(jr) as JObject;  //<---- This line throws the exception
        if (jo != null)
        {                      
            List<JToken> jResults = jo[name + "Result"].Children().ToList();
            foreach (JToken jObjResult in jResults)
            {
                T obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jObjResult.ToString());
                objList.Add(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
return objList;
```

Anyone who can shed some light on this, please do. And Thanks.

**UPDATE: Add Exact Exception Text**

```
Message: "Unexpected end. Line 1, position 1594143."
StackTrace:
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue(Char currentChar)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteToken(JsonReader reader, Int32 initialDepth)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateJObject(JsonReader reader)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader)
       at MY CODE HIDDEN HERE
```

*Note: The exact position varies sometimes, but it always seems to be a number greater than 65536*

Comment: How big is the JSON? Can you post the smallest snippet of it that still fails to parse?

Comment: At what point through the JSON is line # and position ####? Is it likely to be a nice boundary like 65535 characters for example? We need more info really.

Comment: Do you have problem with deserialization or casting into `JObject`?

Comment: Updated question with the exact exception details

Comment: Of all the weird things, I noticed that the value kept changing for the line failure...based on HOW LONG I LOOKED OVER THINGS IN DEBUG MODE!!!.

I changed how I'm processing it and included a thread.sleep command because I have a feeling that the issue has to do with literally overrunning the response stream.  Unfortunately for me the full test takes almost an hour to complete.  But the short version looked promising.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  I figured out what was causing the issue, but it isn't something that's easy to reproduce at all, because it has to do with connection speed.  Literally, the speed at which the response stream is able to supply data.

**The Altered Code**

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    using (JsonTextReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        while (jr.Read())
            if (jr.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
                break;
        jr.Read();

        JsonSerializer Jser = new JsonSerializer();
        while (!sr.EndOfStream && jr.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
        {
            if(jr.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                T tobj = Jser.Deserialize<T>(jr);
                objList.Add(tobj);
            }
            //consume the EndObject tag
            if (jr.TokenType == JsonToken.EndObject)
                jr.Read();
            //Deliberately slow down the process, On purpose, otherwise we will overrun the stream itself and throw an error
            Thread.Sleep(1); //<=== VERY IMPORTANT LINE
        }
    }
}
```

**The explanation**

I found this by checking the stream position at failure.  I noticed that it kept changing, and I finally figured out that the change was based on how long I spent with the process paused in debug mode looking at details.  The longer I spent, the farther the read would get.  So I altered it to manually advance the stream one object at a time (that took some doing as well, but I figured out what the token order was going to be).  Added in a VERY short thread sleep.  And it worked perfectly.

So, in summary.  When loading JSON directly from a response stream over a slow connection....you can actually serialize data FASTER than the response stream can provide it.  It will report an "Unexpected End" in this case.

Comment: When you're loading JSON, you're not serializing it, you're deserializing it.

Comment: IMHO, in 99%, a Thread.Sleep() is the wrong thing to make code work.

Comment: if you are doing this in a task, you may go with `task.delay`.